# SQL Server Management Studio 2012 - Query designer - keep query selected

Tags: ssms

not sure if anyone here can help me, but after more than 4 years of everyday work with SQL Mgmt Studio 2005 and 2008, I now also sometimes have to use the 2012 version, and there's one tiny change which freaks me out: in 2005 and 2008, I got used to edit a query in the query designer and after I finished and clicked ok, the query would remain selected in the code window so I could immediately execute it. Now, with 2012, they seem to have changed that and the selection is cleared after exiting the query designer. So hitting Alt-X right after the close will execute the whole code in the window (which already gave me a hard time yesterday).

Any idea if that is somehow configurable? I have already searched around but couldn't find anything (not even a similar question), but maybe it's just me again using the wrong search terms.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, there is no option to enable/disable this. I checked the registry to be for sure and haven't seen any flag which tends to change this behavior. It would be a bit too much to change such a small behavior with an additional option.

I think your best option is just to adapt to the new behavior, if you like or not. :-)